# EventRegistry.org api query string for multiple keywords

Tags: python, api, url

In my project I have to use the [Eventregistry.org events API](http://eventregistry.org/documentation#searchArticles) to search for specific articles with specific keywords.

The problem is that if I add more than one keyword, it seems to perform an "AND" sort of search instead of an "OR". (searched for ipad alone ~8k results, searched for surface alone ~40k results, searched for ipad surface together got 9 results)

I am using cakephp 3, but I think the language is not the problem, I think is the final url. I went went through the Python project and find some Query.AND(params) and Query.OR(params) so I asume that this can be done?, but I don't know Python.

This is my url:

```
http://eventregistry.org/json/article?ignoreKeywords=&keywords=surface%20ipad&lang=eng&action=getArticles&articlesSortBy=date&resultType=articles&articlesCount=20
```

Here you can test the [API](http://eventregistry.org/documentation#searchArticles)
This is the Python repo on [github](https://github.com/EventRegistry/event-registry-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, their documentation is not overly informative, to say the least.

Looks like they're using some kind of query language, you could probably figure out what things look like by debugging the request generated by the Python script, but if you're not familiar with Python, try using [**their web interface**](http://eventregistry.org/searchArticles) instead, apparently it supports boolean conditions (`OR`, `AND`, `NOT`, the latter being expressed as `-`), which are being composed into a JSON structure:

- **[http://blog.eventregistry.org/.../phrase-search-boolean-keyword-queries-web-interface](http://blog.eventregistry.org/2017/05/14/phrase-search-boolean-keyword-queries-web-interface/)**
- **[http://blog.eventregistry.org/2017/05/15/number-changes-api-users](http://blog.eventregistry.org/2017/05/15/number-changes-api-users/)**

Check your browsers network console to inspect the generated URLs, they'll contain a `query` key that holds a JSON string like this:

```
{"$query":{"$and":[{"$or":[{"keyword":{"$and":["ipad"]}},{"keyword":{"$and":["surface"]}}]}]}}
```

```
{
  "$query": {
    "$and": [
      {
        "$or": [
          {
            "keyword": {
              "$and": [
                "ipad"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": {
              "$and": [
                "surface"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

That looks a little different to what the blog post shows, but it seems that the more compact variant shown there works too:

```
{"$query":{"keyword":{"$or":["ipad","surface"]}}}
```

```
{
  "$query": {
    "keyword": {
      "$or": [
        "ipad",
        "surface"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So the final URL could look like this:

```
http://eventregistry.org/json/article?action=getArticles&articlesCount=20&articlesSortBy=date&resultType=articles&query={"$query":{"keyword":{"$or":["ipad","surface"]}}}
```

```
http://eventregistry.org/json/article
    ?action=getArticles
    &articlesCount=20
    &articlesSortBy=date
    &resultType=articles
    &query={"$query":{"keyword":{"$or":["ipad","surface"]}}}
```